# Sending NSDictionary as NSURLResponse HTTP Body to Web Service

Tags: php, ios, web-services, backend, nsurlrequest

So I have this php script running on my local host as an API for my iOS application. I am sending over an NSURLRequest to the running script on my server but am having problems with having a NSDictionary as the HTTPBody.

Here is how I encode the dictionary object:

```
NSData* data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"command": @"login", @"username": username, @"password": password} options:0 error:nil];
```

So this doesn't work, or rather, I get a null response when I `var_dump()` the `$_POST` variable in the PHP script.

Now, as for this,

```
NSData * data = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"command=login&username=%@&password=%@", username, password] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It works. But I figure it would be cleaner to send over a dictionary object instead of an ugly formatted string.

Is there anything I can do? I guess it would be fine to just generate a string with all the parameters like above, but I think it would be a lot easier to just send over a dictionary object and let the PHP script handle the data in the backend.

I am quite new to implementing backend services as well as internet protocols, and much more involving web development, but I figure I could get some clarification with a simple question on this topic.

**EDIT:**

Here is the built request:

```
NSString *preferredLanguageCodes = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kAPIHost, kAPIPath]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, en-us;q=0.8", preferredLanguageCodes] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData* data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"command": @"login", @"username": username, @"password": password} options:0 error:nil];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
```

Comment: jsonserialization is the right way to go... do you get nil response in data? instead of passing 'nil' for the 'error' argument, pass error object and check what error you get...

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code you use to set add the json and set the content type?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP body shall be string, thus the data shall be converted from string object, or `NSDictionary` that is serialized to String. Try this:

`NSData * bodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:yourDictionaryObj options:0 error:&error];`

`NSString * body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:bodyData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Then use `NSString * body`.